# Loading and pre-filling form from button on separate component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have an edit button on a table that, when clicked, will pull up a form page and prefill the form with the information from the table row where the edit button was clicked.

I am using Router dom to link to the form page but I'm not sure how to send the data from the table page to the form page.

Here is the top of the Table code

```
import React from "react";
import "./PtTable.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class PtTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      patients: null
    };


  getPatients() {
    fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/PtSearchPg")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ patients: data }));
  }
```

Here is the edit button. Right above this is the map of patients from the database.

```
              {this.state.patients.map(patient => (
                <tr key={patient.patientId}>
                  <td>{patient.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{patient.lastName}</td>
                  <td>{patient.dob}</td>
                  <td>{patient.unitId}</td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <Link to="/PtEditPg">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-warning btnspace"
                      >
                        Edit
                      </button>
                    </Link>
```

This is the top of the Edit form. I tried a couple of ways on ptId and firstName with no success. firstName says undefined.

```
import React from "react";
import "./PtForm.css";

class PtEditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ptId: props.ptId,
      firstName: props.patient.firstName,
      lastName: null,
      dob: null,
      address: null,
      address2: null,
      city: null,
      state: null,
      zipCode: null,
      account: null,
      medRecord: null,
      unitId: null,
      states: null
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add those values to the search query

```
 <Link to={`/PtEditPg?firstName=${patient.firstName}&lastName=${patient.lastName}&dob=${patient.dob}&unitId=${patient.unitId}`}>
  <button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-sm btn-warning btnspace"
  >
    Edit
  </button>
</Link>
```

An then read that on the Component using withRouter and some function to get the query values, I always use query-string parse method

```
...
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as qs from 'query-string';

class PtEditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { location } = this.props;
    const { search } = location;
    const query = qs.parse(search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true });

    this.state = {
      ptId: query.ptId || null,
      firstName: query.firstName || null,
      lastName: query.lastName || null,
      dob: query.dob || null,
      address: null,
      address2: null,
      city: null,
      state: null,
      zipCode: null,
      account: null,
      medRecord: null,
      unitId: query.unitId || null,
      states: null
    };
...

export default withRouter(PtEditForm);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: For some reason it is reading as null. I log this.props.location.search and get the following:   ?
                      firstName=Josh&
                      lastName=Smith&
                      dob=1991-06-03&
                      unitId=1 but after I parse I log query.firstName and get back null